# Desktop file won't play video after booting

Tags: .desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Splash
Icon=
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Categories=Applications;Splash
Exec=vlc --quiet -f --no-video-title-show /$HOME/videos/boot_video.mp4 vlc://quit
```

---

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Splash
Icon=
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Categories=Applications;Splash
Exec=vlc --quiet -f --no-video-title-show $HOME/videos/boot_video.mp4 vlc://quit
```

Neither of the above pieces of code will start the video after my PC boots. However, if I do not use the $HOME variable and explicitly call out the path to the video, the video starts no problem.

The code below starts the video with no issues.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Splash
Icon=
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Categories=Applications;Splash
Exec=vlc --quiet -f --no-video-title-show /home/TestUser/videos/boot_video.mp4 vlc://quit
```

---

In terminal, when I type $HOME, I see the output of "bash: /home/TestUser: Is a directory". I'm very new to .desktop files and having a difficult time here. Appreciate the help!

Cheers!

Comment: My guess is that .desktop files somehow do not recognize the $HOME variable. Not sure how to handle this situation then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that what I'm trying to accomplish is possible. I read through the spec and there isn't anything on escape characters for $. I tried using \ to escape it and it didn't work. I will explicitly call out the file path.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118422/proper-use-of-escape-characters-in-desktop-file?newreg=8a52afdc130f4c2aaf68f8db49568335

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. If you want to read what is in home, you will have to run ECHO $HOME. Just typing $HOME is the equivalent of typing /home/TestUser and therefore what you got from bash is what you would get if you typed any path. For an answer to your question have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980464/how-do-i-access-an-environment-variable-in-a-desktop-files-exec-line

Answer (score 0):

I Guess to adding your `.desktop` file with,

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

and setup your Autostart Gnome where app want to startup automatically.